# Getting data from socket on Android

Tags: java, android, sockets

So I have this really, really strange problem with getting data using socket from server which is working on my PC to Android app. All in local network for now.
It is strange, because I wrote server and client apps (both using sockets) to send and get data and it works really great. I tried to do exactly the same on Android and it gets only first response from server, but not the rest after sending token.
I searched through SO and saw piece of advice that available() method is not right so I changed it and it's still not working as I wish it would.
I think there is something wrong with server-side app or android app works way too fast for server and it sends data after ending transmission on android, but I tried to give it a bit of time and nothing...

This is server app (in general it gets token, lets say "RAM" then it gets output from linux process and sends it straight to android app):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;

public class BLCServer extends Thread{
private ServerSocket serverSocket;

public BLCServer(int port) throws IOException {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    serverSocket.setSoTimeout(86400000);
}

public void run() {
    while(true) {
        try {
            String token = "";
            System.out.println("Waiting for a client on port: "+serverSocket.getLocalPort());
            Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Just connected to " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            System.out.println("Beginning transmission");

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(in.readUTF());

            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            out.writeUTF("Thanks for connecting to " + server.getLocalSocketAddress() + "Goodbye\n");


            while(token != "END") {
                token = in.readUTF();
                if(token.equals("RAM")) {
                    Ram ram = new Ram();
                    List<String> ramData = new ArrayList<>();
                    ramData = ram.getRamData();
                    System.out.println("RAM");
                    System.out.println("ram.size(): " + ramData.size());

                    out.writeUTF("ramBeginning");

                    for(String x : ramData) {
                        System.out.println("Wysyłam do clienta: " + x);
                        out.writeUTF(""+x);
                    }
                    out.writeUTF("ramEnd");

                } else if(token.equals("CPU")) {
                    Cpu cpu = new Cpu();
                    List<String> cpuData = new ArrayList<>();
                    cpuData = cpu.getCpuLoad();
                    System.out.println("CPU");

                    out.writeUTF("cpuBeginning");
                    for(String x : cpuData) {
                        out.writeUTF(x);
                    }
                    out.writeUTF("cpuEnd");

                } else if(token.equals("STORAGE")) {
                    Storage storage = new Storage();
                    List<String> storageData = new ArrayList<>();
                    storageData = storage.printStorageData();
                    System.out.println("STORAGE");

                    out.writeUTF("storageBeginning");
                    for(String x : storageData) {
                        out.writeUTF(x);
                    }
                    out.writeUTF("storageEnd");

                } else if(token.equals("UPTIME")) {
                    Uptime uptime = new Uptime();
                    String uptimeData = uptime.getUptime();
                    System.out.println("UPTIME");

                    out.writeUTF("uptimeBeginning");
                    out.writeUTF(uptimeData);

                    out.writeUTF("uptimeEnd");

                } else if(token.equals("TEMPERATURES")) {
                    out.writeUTF("temperaturesBeginning");


                    out.writeUTF("temperaturesEnd");


                } else if(token.equals("END")) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    out.writeUTF("Token unknown");
                }
            }


            server.close();         
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {
            System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
            break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int port = 1984;
    try {
        Thread t = new BLCServer(port);
        t.start();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

And also there is android main activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

TextView cpuT;
TextView ramT;
TextView uptimeT;
TextView storageT;

List<String> ram = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> cpu = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> uptime = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> storage = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> temperatures = new ArrayList<String>();


public class NetThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    String dstAddress = "192.168.0.111";
    int dstPort = 1984;


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {

        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
            OutputStream outToServer = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

            InputStream inFromServer = new PushbackInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);

            out.writeUTF("Hello from " + socket.getLocalSocketAddress());

            int singleByte;
            ramT.setText(in.readUTF());

            out.writeUTF("RAM");

            while((singleByte = inFromServer.read()) != -1) { // there was code like: while(in.available() > 0) { ... } but someone wrote about it's bad behaviour on SO
                ramT.setText(ramT.getText() + "\n" + singleByte);
            }
            }

            out.writeUTF("END");
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.d("WEBSERVICE", "Oncreate wywołane\n");
    cpuT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayCpu);
    ramT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayRam);
    uptimeT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayUptime);
    storageT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayStorage);



    NetThread netThread = new NetThread();
    netThread.execute("RAM", "STORAGE", "UPTIME");

}

}
```

In addition I paste you client application for pc:

```
public class BLCClient {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String serverName = "localhost";
    int port = 1984;

    try {
        System.out.println("Connecting to..."+serverName+" on port 1984");
        Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
        System.out.println("Just connected to "+client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

        InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);

        Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
        String token = "";

        out.writeUTF("Hello from " + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
        System.out.println("Server says: "+in.readUTF());

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Podaj token ciulu: ");
            token = cin.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Twój token: " + token);

            if(token.equals("END")) {
                out.writeUTF(token);
                break;
            } else {
                out.writeUTF(token);
                System.out.println(in.readUTF());
                System.out.println("IN: " + in.available());
                while(in.available() > 0) {
                    System.out.println(in.readUTF());
                }
            }
        }

        client.close();
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Yes. I'm using part of code from tutorialspoint.com. If you need classes for getting data for ram, cpu, storage, temperatures or uptime processes let me know.
For now I've spent around 4 days trying to figure out what is wrong with my code for android (because servers sends data correctly, I'm 99% sure). Please help me. I'm powerless and I want this app wake to work so so badly right now (Actually I made this work using tomcat server, but I want my own server in here).

Thanks.

Comment: 'but not the rest after sending token.'. But does the server receive that token? You are talking about RAM i think. Add an out.flush() after the out.writeUTF. Both in client and server.

Comment: Yeah. Server receives token every time. I added flush() method after sending out data and now it works, but not always. I don't know why, but sometimes app suspends at first or second reading data from server. Gosh I have no idea what is wrong in here. When I made it working I tried to send at first number of data packages so I could read it in the loop. And for some reasons app doesn't work anymore. Few tries more and it's working. Damn...
Anyway thanks for your help. I think it's piece of advice for years now.